# Formula to return string value based on ranked categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Example image]

This question might have a very simple answer.
I have 3 values (i.e. Low, High and Extreme) that correspond with 5 categories (Low, Moderate, High, Very High and Extreme), ranked from low to high.

I want to find a formula that returns the highest-ranked string value (i.e. Extreme), without having to add extra columns for category or value scores.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Please use text tables when possible. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate a problem, which clearly isn't the case here. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [ask].

Comment: Your question is not clear? How excel will know that max is extreme as it is just text?

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to do, but need to know if are an O365 user or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=@SORTBY(B2:B4,MATCH(B2:B4,A2:A6,0),-1)
```

Note that the order in 'B' does not matter as long the order in 'A' is correct.

Comment: Worked very nicely. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one approach, which *does* require O365 because of the FILTER() function.  This would be simpler if we knew for sure how many values were in your *values* column.  Since I don’t know that, I ended up adding a little complexity with the FILTER() function.  This prevents the MATCH() function from returning #N/As for blank values, which in turn would break the MAX() function:

`=INDEX({"Low","Medium","High","Very High","Extreme"},MAX(MATCH(FILTER(A1:A5,A1:A5<>""), {"Low","Medium","High","Very High","Extreme"},0)))`

This can be further reduced by the LET() function:

```
=LET(
categories, {"Low","Medium","High","Very High","Extreme"},
INDEX(categories,MAX(MATCH(FILTER(A1:A5,A1:A5<>""),categories,0)))
)
```

Also, if this is a sheet that will get a lot of re-use, you could make the *categories* a named value using the Excel Name Manager.  If you did that the formula would simply be:

```
=INDEX(categories,MAX(MATCH(FILTER(A1:A5,A1:A5<>""),categories,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! There are always three values in the value column so that might simplify things a bit more.